# PyGears - Can't run script, PYPY is undefined

Tags: python, pygears

I am trying to setup PyGears, I have installed the package using pip. I am trying to execute the bellow two lines of code using command line.

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
from pygears.typing import Uint
```

This is the error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygears import gear, Intf
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygears\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pygears.typing
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygears\typing\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygears.conf import PluginBase, reg
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygears\conf\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .trace import pygears_excepthook, register_issue, MultiAlternativeError
  File "C:\Users\Nikola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygears\conf\trace.py", line 400, in <module>
    elif PYPY:
NameError: name 'PYPY' is not defined
```

To my understanding, PyPy is an alternative interpreter to CPython, but I am unsure whether the symbol mentioned above is related to this. Should I try configuring PyPy as my interpreter or is this issue caused by something else?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: this has been fixed by https://github.com/bogdanvuk/pygears/commit/a27df7ce62cfe568978fad1f39d87372b5b9a531

---

This looks like a bug in pygears. If you try with python >= 3.7, you should not run into this error.

I submitted a bug report: https://github.com/bogdanvuk/pygears/issues/8